# Masstransit failed host connection

Tags: masstransit

I use the `MassTransit.AspNetCore`package to integrate `masstransit` to `asp.net core`. So I have the following code in my `Startup.cs` class:

```
IBusControl CreateBus(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.Host(Configuration["rabbitMqUrl"], h =>
                {
                    h.Username(Configuration["rabbitMqUsername"]);
                    h.Password(Configuration["rabbitMqPassword"]);
                });
            });
        }

        services.AddMassTransit(CreateBus);
```

And the issue is that if the rabbit mq is not available my application tries to reconnect to the host. Is there any way to configure number of attempts - let's say stop trying to reconnect after 3 attempts so my application can run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bus.StartAsync()` method accepts a `CancellationToken`, which can be used to cancel starting the bus. There is an overload that accepts a `TimeSpan` which can be used to specify a timeout for the connection.

The hosted service also accepts a cancellationToken, but I'm not sure how ASP.NET Core determines what to pass to it and how to setup a timeout.

Comment: Thanks! I get the idea, but still I'm not sure if it's possible to allow the application to continue to run. If I pass the cancellation token it causes `RabbitMqException` and the application finishes.

Comment: Even if I handle exception it throws another one which says that the bus has been already started. Is there any way not to start the bus while configuring it in ASP.Net Core with the code I described in the question?

Comment: If the broker connection cannot be established, why would you want your application to run? It would just fail later on, leaving it running in a mode where it isn't available.